# Adding column to higher dimension

Tags: python, numpy

let's assume that i have array called A

```
A = np.zeros((4, 3, 2))

array([[[0., 0.],
    [0., 0.],
    [0., 0.]],
   [[0., 0.],
    [0., 0.],
    [0., 0.]],
   [[0., 0.],
    [0., 0.],
    [0., 0.]],
   [[0., 0.],
    [0., 0.],
    [0., 0.]]])
```

and another array called B

```
B = np.arange(4)
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

and i want to do something like concatenation in the third dimension to got this result:

```
array([[[0., 0., 0.0],
    [0., 0., 0.0],
    [0., 0., 0.0]],
   [[0., 0., 1.0],
    [0., 0., 1.0],
    [0., 0., 1.0]],
   [[0., 0., 2.0],
    [0., 0., 2.0],
    [0., 0., 2.0]],
   [[0., 0., 3.0],
    [0., 0., 3.0],
    [0., 0., 3.0]]])
```

i tried serval ways to do that but i didn't succeed.
who i can do that in good way not loops?

Answer (score 1):

To add the extra dimension you can use `np.append`. You just have to get the shape correct. You can use `np.repeat()` to make the repeating elements:

```
A = np.zeros((4, 3, 2))
h, w, d = A.shape
B = np.repeat(np.arange(h), w).reshape([h, w, 1])

np.append(A, B, axis=2)
```

Output:

```
array([[[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1.]],

       [[0., 0., 2.],
        [0., 0., 2.],
        [0., 0., 2.]],

       [[0., 0., 3.],
        [0., 0., 3.],
        [0., 0., 3.]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

We could broadcast `B` to the corresponding shape and use [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) here and assign `B` broadcasted across the corresponding axes:

```
np.concatenate([A, np.broadcast_to(B[:,None,None], A[...,-1:].shape)], -1)
```

---

```
print(A)

array([[[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1.]],

       [[0., 0., 2.],
        [0., 0., 2.],
        [0., 0., 2.]],

       [[0., 0., 3.],
        [0., 0., 3.],
        [0., 0., 3.]]])
```

Comment: what is the meaning of `-1:` in `A[:,:,-1:].shape` ? @yatu

Comment: I'm taking the shape of `A` indexing on the last column as a reference to reshape `B` @HaithamFadila